# Define own feedback messages in Wicket

Tags: wicket

How do I define my own feedback messages in Wicket?
For example: if I give an incorrect username, I want to get an error message like "The user name in incorrect, try to login again." instead of using the default error message.

What would an example be like?

Answer (score 29):

You can display your own error messages using `error()` and `warn()` and `info()`. If you want to show errors dependent on validators or the required flag you can define a properties file with the same name as the class which contains a mapping of field -> message. For example:

**Index.java**

```
Form form = new Form("myform");
form.add(new TextField("name").setRequired(true));
form.add(new PasswordTextField("password").setRequired(true));
form.add(new TextField("phonenumber").setRequired(true));
```

**Index.properties**

```
Required=Provide a ${label} or else...
```

All required fields

```
myform.name.Required=You have to provide a name
```

The field `name` in the form `myform` when it is required.

```
password.Required=You have to provide a password
```

Any field with the name `password` when it is required.

```
phonenumber.Required=A telephone number is obligatory.
```

Any field with the name `phonenumber` when it is required.

This shows a variety of ways of setting a feedback message for specific components.

You can also put the properties files next to the following component level (in order of importance, top highest):

- Page Class
- Component Class
- Your Application Class
- Wickets Application Class

Hope that helps

Comment: How does it work with messages of Validators? You used just the setRequired method.

Answer (score 2):

@user1090145: I've used overloaded Component's **error()** method in Validator's class:

```
private void error(IValidatable<String> validatable, String errorKey) {
    ValidationError error = new ValidationError();
    error.addMessageKey(errorKey);
    validatable.error(error);
}
```

and invoked it in **validate()** by

```
error(validatable, "your-form.field.text-id");
```

Properties **your-form.field.text-id** must be defined in **YourPage.properties**

Sources:
[Create custom validator in Wicket](http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/create-custom-validator-in-wicket/) and 
[Form validation messages](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Form+validation+messages)

Answer (score 1):

you should set Feed back message to Session

```
message = "message";
Session.get().getFeedbackMessages().success(null, message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous IValidationError class and the messageSource.getMessage method to get a custom message from your property file:

```
error(new IValidationError() {
    @Override
    public Serializable getErrorMessage(IErrorMessageSource messageSource) {
        //create a list of the arguments that you will use in your message string
        Map<String, Object> vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        vars.put("invalidUsername", getInvalidUsernameInput());

        //get the message string from the property file
        return messageSource.getMessage("mysettings.invalid_username", vars);
    }
});
```

Sample property file:

```
mysettings.invalid_username=The user name "${invalidUsername}" is incorrect.
```