# Changing Wicket text field validation error message

Tags: wicket

I have a text field that uses a PropertyModel, like this:

```
TextField<Integer> ageField = new TextField<Integer>("age", 
                      new PropertyModel<Integer>(person, "age"));
```

When a non-integer value is submitted, the following error is displayed in the browser:

```
"The value of 'age' is not a valid Integer."
```

How can I modify this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was adding this to the properties file:

```
<entry key="IConverter.Integer">${label} must be an integer.</entry>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Wicket 6 you need to set up a properties file with the inputs Wicket-ID appended by `.Required`:

```
myinput.Required = Please provide this input field
```

[Define own feedback messages in Wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739414/define-own-feedback-messages-in-wicket)

Answer (score 3):

Create a [properties file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Everything+about+Wicket+internationalization) and specify your own message:

TextField.age=Your custom message

More info about properties [here](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/i18n.html) and [here](https://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/resource/loader/ComponentStringResourceLoader.html)

Answer (score 2):

Add 
    `age.IConverter.Integer = Your Custom Message`
to your properties file